# jQuery Animate Div Scroll back to top

Tags: jquery

I have a div which has the content:

```
<div id="First">There are lots of content in here. Blah Blah Blah...</div>
```

The `div` has a style attribute of `overflow:auto;` so if any content were to overflow, a scrollbar would appear. I have a button inside the div at the end of the content.

Since the content inside the div could allow for a deep scroll, is there anyway, that on click of the button it will move the scroll back to the top of the div?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes. Use [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Just provide your element and a value of 0 like this:

```
$('#id').scrollTop(0);
```

You can also animate the scrolling back to top like this:

```
$('#id').animate({
   scrollTop: 0
}, 'slow');
```

Comment: Advice to other Firefox users, when testing the new code, open the page in a new tab. My version of Firefox seems to cache the old scroll position and only opening the page in a new tab will allow the new code to take effect. (FF 57.0.4 (64-bit) for Ubuntu)

Answer (score 5):

You do not need jQuery (or even JavaScript) for this.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/syjbT/)

Define an anchor name:

```
<a name="top"></a>
```

And create a link to this anchor at the bottom:

```
<a href="#top">back to top</a>​
```

Comment: +1 for calling to attention that jQuery (or even js for that matter) is unnecessary. You have to make a few changes if you decide that you want to animate the scrolling, but I think its important to remind people that jQuery doesn't need to be a knee-jerk reaction to every problem.

Comment: +1 Despite the misleading title "Animate Div Scroll" you gave the right answer

Comment: @SanBluecat Are you sure the title is misleading? I would default to assuming the title is correct and that the OP wants to know how to scroll with an animation. Nothing in the question seems to contradict that.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ScrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) if you are dealing with a y-overflow and/or [ScrollLeft](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) for x-overflow.

```
$('#yourbuttonid').click(function() {
    $('#First').scrollTop(0);//for vertical scroll
    $('#First').scrollLeft(0);//for horizontal scroll
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#scrollToTopButton').click(function(){
    $('#First').scrollTop(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OVERKILL!!!
Using scrollTop, or jquery for that matter... for such a simple task may not be advisable. Use anchors instead:

```
<a name="pageTop"></a>
....
<a href="#pageTop">TOP</a>
```

Or is there something more you want to do / achieve?